# How to call a method in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a class file cls_PurchaseValidae.cs in which i have written a code like below:

```
public void txtMfgDate_Validating(TextBox txtMfgDate,ErrorProvider errorProvider1,string datetoValidate)
{
  //method for validating the text box.
  ValidateMfgDate(txtMfgDate, errorProvider1,datetoValidate);
}
```

and i m calling this event in the code behind frm_Purchase.cs like this:

```
private void txtMfgDate_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
   objPurchaseValid.txtMfgDate_Validating(txtMfgDate,errorProvider1,datetoValidate);
 }
```

but i m getting the error:

> Error 1   The name 'datetoValidate' does
>   not exist in the current context

How can i resolve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is datetoValidate declared and how?

Comment: the title of this question is very misleading. this is a basic syntax issue. either you haven't declared that `dateToValidate` variable properly, or you haven't imported a namespace, etc. Has nothing to do with "3 tier architecture".

Comment: private bool ValidateMfgDate(TextBox txtMfgDate, ErrorProvider errorProvider1,string datetoValidate)
 {
   }

Comment: that's not what we asked. we asked how you declare `dateToValidate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why do you want to pass around *both* `TextBox txtMfgDate`, *and* `string datetoValidate`? Shouldn’t `datetoValidate` be always `txtMfgDate.Text`? Anyway, you can do:

```
private void txtMfgDate_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   objPurchaseValid.txtMfgDate_Validating(txtMfgDate,errorProvider1,txtMfgDate.Text);
}
```

if that is what you want.